# Difference between VMOVDQA and VMOVAPS?

Tags: assembly, x86, sse, avx

I read the ISA reference and I am clear that the 2 instructions differ in the type of value they load (integer vs single precision float). What I don't understand is that the effect of the load is same regardless of the datatype, it should just copy the values from source to destination.

My question is, are there some differences that I am overlooking which necessitate the different types of instructions? Would using VMOVDQA to move some data from memory to a register and then performing float operations on it create some issues?

Comment: Only possible performance effects, like FP vs. SIMD-integer bypass latency.  (Especially for the `movaps reg,reg` form, notably on Nehalem before mov-elimination was a thing.)

Comment: One loads the number into the integer domain, the other into the floating point domain.  Cross domain penalties apply if you load into the wrong one for the instructions that use the data you loaded.  Additionally, `MOVDQA` is SSE2 and later only while `MOVAPS` is SSE1.  Similarly, `VMOVDQA` is AVX2 while `VMOVAPS` is AVX1.

Comment: @fuz: Actually `vmovdqa` (even for ymm regs) only requires AVX1.  https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/movdqa:vmovdqa32:vmovdqa64.  (It's no hardship for AVX1 CPUs; they can just decode it exactly the same as `vmovaps` if they don't have a SIMD-integer domain that wide.)  Fun fact: even [`vptest ymm, ymm`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/ptest) surprisingly only requires AVX1, like [`vtestps`](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vtestpd:vtestps) (same but only the high bit of each dword)

Comment: @fuz: Forgot to mention: `vmovdqa xmm` has to be supported by AVX1, along with VEX-encoded 128-bit versions of all SSE4.2 and earlier instructions.  So it made sense to let the 256-bit versions decode on AVX1 CPUs when that didn't take any extra hardware in any execution units.